# What does ΔC and ΔN mean with regards to a protein sequence?

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins

I am reading a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Trevor_Dale/publication/11165081_The_Regulation_of_Glycogen_Synthase_Kinase-3_Nuclear_Export_by_FratGBP/links/09e41510bb9aa7e04a000000.pdf) about the regulation of the nuclear export of the protein GSK3 and I have come across the following statement:

> Full-length FLAG epitope-tagged mFrat1 (FLAG-Frat) and the
> amino-terminal half of Frat (ΔC Frat) localized predominantly to the
> cytoplasm of transfected MDCK cells (Fig. 1, A and B, i and iii).
> Unexpectedly, the carboxyl-terminal half of Frat (ΔN Frat) accumulated
> preferentially in the nuclei of transfected cells (Fig. 1B, iv).

I am not sure why the amino-terminal and carboxyl-terminal half of the Frat protein are referred to as ΔC Frat and ΔN Frat respectively. I know that the amino terminus of a protein is also referred to as the N-terminus, whilst the carboxyl terminus of a protein is referred to as the C-terminus. I am not sure why in this paper ΔC and ΔN are used to refer to the amino-terminal and carboxyl-terminal half of the Frat protein.

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: This is just a simple technical abbreviation. Δ is used to mean deletion, so ΔC is used for the N-terminal fragment  as the C-terminal part has been deleted. One shouldn’t write answers in comments, but this doesn’t need any more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Frat/GBP (frequently rearranged in T-cell lymphomas/GSK-3-binding protein) protein is a proto-oncogene that regulates the Wnt signalling pathway. (van Amerongen *et al.*, 2004)

The cited paper (Franca-Koh, 2002) noted a correlation between some forms of Frat and GSK3 cellular localization. Without Frat, GSK3 is cytoplasmic. In the presence of Frat, the heterodimer Frat-GSK3 translocates to the nucleus. As Frat is phosphorylated, it was unclear then what mechanism(s) was(were) involved. To investigate the role of Frat, the authors hypothesized that a region of Frat may be involved, not necessarily the whole protein.

They engineered deletion constructs and added an *N*-terminal FLAG tag for easy affinity purification. They used the symbol delta (Δ) for deletion. The *N*-terminal region of residues 1 – 129 encompassing Domain 1, *i.e.* deletion of the *C*-terminal region is called ΔC; likewise, the *C*-terminal region of residues 129-274 encompassing Domain 2, *i.e.* deletion of the *N*-terminus is called ΔN. They also engineered a green fluorescent protein (GFP) tag fusion protein variant. Here are their constructs as illustrated on Figure 1 of their paper:

[image: Molecules]

**Human ortholog**
I aligned the residue sequence of the murine Frat with the human orthologs: it has 79% identity to human Frat1 and 68% identity to human Frat2. mFrat residues 1 – 129 (ΔC) and 129 – 274 (ΔN) correspond to hFrat1 residues 1 – 132 and 132 – 279, respectively.

**Added Note**
Here is a co-crystal structure of **GSK3β** (*N*-terminal lobe in orange and *C*-terminal lobe in cyan) complexed with Frat1 peptide 197-226 (forest green) and an inhibitor (*N*-(6-(3,4-dihydroxyphenyl)-1*H*-pyrazolo[3,4-*b*]pyridin-3-*yl*)acetamide) (green) as deposited with RCSB as [entry 5OY4.pdb](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/5OY4) . The presence of the inhibitor helps locate the active site in the image of the GSK3b protein kinase. 
[image: Molecules]

**References**
[Franca-Koh, J., Yeo, M., Fraser, E., Young, N. and Dale, T.C. (2002) *J. Biol. Chem.* **277**:43844-43848.](https://doi.org/10.1074/jbc.M207265200)

[Van Amerongen, R., van der Gulfen, H., Bleeker, F., Jonkers, J. and Berns, A. (2004) *J. Biol. Chem.* **279**:26967-26974.](https://doi.org/10.1074/jbc.M400439200)